# mysql query on integer returns no rows

Tags: mysql, integer

my usage table has a column usSEQ which is integer(11) (auto_increment)

```
SELECT * FROM usage WHERE usSEQ = 38098
```

returns no rows.

```
SELECT * FROM usage WHERE usSEQ <= 38098

SELECT * FROM usage WHERE usSEQ >= 38098
```

both return many rows, including the one with 38098

```
SELECT * FROM usage WHERE usSEQ >= 38098 and usSEQ <= 38098
```

returns no rows. What am I missing here?

Comment: can use post your table with data?

Comment: it's weird that when you execute `usSEQ = 38098` there is no row return but if `usSEQ <= 38098` or `usSEQ >= 38098`, it will return row including `38098`.

Comment: @JW웃 That's the point of his question.

Comment: What if you do `WHERE usSEQ BETWEEN 38090 AND 38100`?

Comment: @Barmar yes `:)` I'm confused on the problem. I have nothing against it..

Comment: Probably you are missing something else. I don't see any issue [with your queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e43d/2). Everything works fine

Comment: If he can give the table with data then, We can find the actual problem.

Comment: Either you're misreading the output or you have a typo in your query.

Comment: `usSEQ >= 38098 and usSEQ <= 38098` is the same as `usSEQ = 38098`

Answer (score 1):

Better you can change your query to "SELECT * FROM usage WHERE usSEQ = 38098 "   which is equal to  "SELECT * FROM usage WHERE usSEQ >= 38098 and usSEQ <= 38098"

Answer (score 0):

UMMMM embarrassing answer! 
Not being very familiar with the UI to mySQL, and it being late in the day, I was seeing the top line :
"Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0245 sec)" and interpreting it as 0 rows returned. The data was appearing in the jumbled mess below.
Sorry about the confusion and thanks for the responses. The world in the morning is a much clearer place.